# jQuery validation - Display error message for each field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

http://jsfiddle.net/nXqd/qC2Ya/6/

Take a look at the jsfiddle. When I enter wrong data in two inputs and clicking submit, I only receive the error message on the first one. Now I want two of them which have the `name` attribute in the form displayed as well.

In this example, I use the same name on purpose to get these values on the backend easier. I just loop through the list and get all information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You have added same name for both fields. Same name attributes are used to combine the fields in a group. You have to use class based validation.

Comment: actually, I use the same name on purpose which is getting information easier on the back end.
If I change to using class based - ( use $.each ?, tell me if I'm wrong ). 
A group of fields will be added at run time so I have to bind the validate for them ? ( a group may have 6 fields )

Comment: Yes you are wrong. class based validation doesn't need $.each. its quite simple. if you could see the validation plugin demo. Its fairly simple. and its the best choice if you have dynamically added fields

Answer (score 1):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xr5g6/1/

Hope it fits your needs. `:)`

**code**

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        number: {required: true, range: [1,2]},
        number2: {required: true, range: [1,2]}
    }
});
```

​**html**

```
<form name="myForm">
<fieldset>
<legend>My Form</legend>
    <label for='number'>Number</label>
    <input name='number'class='required'/> <br />
    <label for='number'>Number</label>
    <input name='number2' class='required'/>
    <label for='change-range'>Max range</label>
    <input name='change-range' class='required'/>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit">
</form>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use different `name` attriburtes for different inputs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xYTNw/